# How to get the method of backBarButtonItem of navigationItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, backbarbuttonitem

I have add the `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` when turn to the new page like the following code , but I want to add a `Timer` for change some image before turn back to the first by `backBarButtonItem`.

```
    UIViewController *ReconnectView = [[AITReconnectView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AITReconnectView" bundle:nil] ;      
    ReconnectView.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;          
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];               
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:ReconnectView animated:YES];
```

For example : When I click the `backBarButtonItem` , it will run the `Timer` for 3 second. And then turn back to the first view.

I have search for some information , but it only overwrite the new method for `backBarButtonItem`.

How to add a `Timer` in method of `backBarButtonItem` but retain the original method of `backBarButtonItem` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Apple doesn't permit us handle event of `backBarButton`. You can make a backBarButton by yourself and set it to `leftBarButtonItem`, and handle event for it

Comment: If the user expects to go back, why are you delaying the event?

Comment: @MarkRamotowski I want to change image and show some information for user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Create your own back button (similar like native) and selector method and assign it to button:

   > ```
   > UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BackToVcA"
   >                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
   >                                                               target:self
   >                                                               action:@selector(addAction:)] autorelease];
   >
   > self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
   > ```
2. Use UIViewController life cycle method, `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I try to add a timer in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`. But the view turn back to the first view and didn't wait for timer finish. When the view turn to the first view , the timer still count...

Comment: I know the first way which you post. But I don't know how to turn back to the first view by code.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to delay the transition to the first view by 3 seconds,
  Just add,
     `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];` to `viewWillDisappear`method of the second view.
- If you want to execute method invocation in objective C, then
      `[self performSelector:@selector(methodName) withObject:self afterDelay:3.0];` 
  should work fine. Share code for some more information.